# List and Group Orders by Artist and Songs

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, include, nested-loops

I have created a functioning e-commerce platform where Members can buy songs. Everything works fine, But I would like to group all of my Orders in my Index Page by Artist.

Currently I am able to group each Author with its corresponding albums, But each ordered song is then listed multiple times under each album.

**How can I list all of the Ordered Songs corresponding to an Album without duplicating the Song Title and Providing a Counter that shows the Total Orders?**

```
EX. of what I'd like in my Orders Page

###Orders grouped by Artists (which I've Done)
Artist1
  Album1                      ###List of Albums Corresponding to an Artist 
    --Song1 (10 0rders)          (which I've Done)
    --Song3 (5 Orders)
  Album2 
    --Song5 (2 Orders)        ###Ordered Songs Corresponding to an Album (NEED HELP)
  Album3                      ###No Duplicates, only list ordered songs with a counter 

Artist2
  Album1 
    --Song2 (1 Orders)
  Album2 

Artist3
  Album1 
    --Song4 (1 Orders)
```

MODELS

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :artist_id, :album_id, :user_id, :order_date

  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :user

end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :albums
  has_many :songs, :through => :albums
  has_many :orders, :through => :songs

end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :artist_id

  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :songs
  has_many :orders, :through => :songs

end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :artist_id, :album_id, :title, :price

  belongs_to :album
  has_many :orders

end
```

CONTROLLERS

```
def index    
  @artists = Artist.includes(:orders).where('orders.id IS NOT NULL')    
end
```

VIEWS

```
<% @artists.each do |artist| %>   ###Lists All Artista with Orders
  <h3><%= artist.name %></h3>

  <% artist.albums.each do |album| %>   ###Lists all Albums Corresponding to Artist
      <h4><%= album.name %></h4>

     <% album.orders.each do |order| %> ###Lists All Ordered Song Titles & Price
       <%= order.song.title %><br>      ###How can i list each ordered song with a counter
       <%= order.song.price %><br>
     <% end %>

  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with

```
   <% @artists.each do |artist| %>
     <h3><%= artist.name %></h3>

     <% artist.albums.each do |album| %>
       <h4><%= album.name %></h4>

         <% album.songs.each do |song| %>

           <% if song.orders.count >= 1 %>
             (<%= song.orders.count %>)
             <%= song.title %>
             $<%= song.price %><br>
           <% end %>

         <% end %> 


     <% end %>

   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but might be worth trying...

Use `group_by` to create arrays of the `album.orders` grouped in a hash by `song.title`. Loop through the hash. Output just the title and price of the first element of each hash. Count the array elements in the hash to get a counter of this song.

```
<% orders_hash = album.orders.group_by{|o|o.song.title} %>

<% orders_hash.each do |order_array| %>
  <%= order_array[0].song.title %>
  <%= order_array[0].song.price %>
  <%= order_array.count %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: it seems to work if i don't add song.title to the order_array, otherwise i get this error undefined method `song' for "title name":String

Comment: The order_array should be an array of full orders... and each order beloongs to song and song has an attribute title, so `order_array.first.song.title` (or `order_array[0].song.title`) should work. If you can 'pry', you may want to check that orders_hash is a hash with key being song title and value being an array of order objects.